# Convert byte to Domain objects

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4, blazeds

A Java developer just asked me the following:

If I send you byte[] for all the method calls on Remote Objects - will you be able to convert it to domain objects?

Can this be done? And how?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Comment: See the comment on FlexCoders...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. It won't happen automatically (ie, like it would if IExternalizable was implemented on both ends), but there's no reason you can't have, for example, a `fromBytes` static method on your domain objects which accept a `ByteArray` and construct the object from that.

Comment: What's the advantage for a Java developer doing it this way? I guess I'm just used to creating a DTO that has the same properties with the Remote alias metadata tag pointing to the Java class.

Comment: No idea why he would want to do that. Maybe he's crazy? Maybe he's brilliant? It really depends on the data involved… Maybe ask him?

Comment: I just got the explanation from the Java guy: He says that the standard serialization with BlazeDS works only when the Java class follows the Java Bean convention, i.e. public constructor, no args...etc..

Some of his classes do not do this because they are composite classes...

Anyway, he is fixing it on his end. Thanks for helping me understsand. I was beginning to think my standard way of doing things was too simple.

Comment: Ah, that does make sense from the Java end. And no problem :)